# Why do other outlets not work after I changed one?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

Yesterday I changed a wall outlet that had more than two hot and two white wires with a total of about 6 wires on the outlet. Two hot and two white were connected to the old outlet so I just connected the new one the same way (I think) and push the rest back in how they were. Well, the new outlet works but two of the other outlets in the room, each on different walls do not. They all worked before. What do I do? Do I need to create a pigtail or could I have connect a wrong hot wire? I could provide photos if needed.

Comment: Yes, _please_ [edit] your post to include sharp, focused pics of the wiring on both sides of the new outlet and show the wiring all the way to into the back of the box. Show a pic of the old outlet, as well. If you know for certain, also label (physically before the pic or digitally after) the "hot" cable that leads back to the panel. If you're not sure, ask for help in identifying that cable.

Comment: Also, in your edit, please include all the "before" pics you've got. They will help tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Check your existing connections with the photos of the original connections before you took them apart.

Either you changed something or made an incorrect connection to the new fitting compared to the old one , so those photos from before will help you sort the issue.

Comment: That's mighty bold of you to assume "before" photos were taken! But, it's an excellent point. Copy/Pasta as an answer to every "help, my wiring used to work but now it doesn't" question. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan well op did say photos could be provided, I take before photos - commonsense and with smartphones so easy... before I used to do a diagram on the back of a fag packet...

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right, he did! My bad...